# Can a IDataSet in dbunit be created using a ListArray of objects

Tags: java, dbunit

I do not want to use the Xml/dtd files to create a `IDataSet` in my dbunit `Java` class that extends `DatabaseTestCase`, Can it be created using a `List<myOjectInstances> objs;`

I can't find any other solutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `DefaultDataSet` intialized by a `DefaultTable`? The latter can be easily constructed in code from one or more lists:

```
DefaultTable fourColTable = new DefaultTable("4COLUMNTABLE",
            new Column[] { 
                new Column("COL1", DataType.BIGINT),
                new Column("COL2", DataType.BIGINT),
                new Column("COL3", DataType.VARCHAR),
                new Column("COL4", DataType.VARCHAR)
                });
for (int i = 0; i < someVal; i++)
    fourColTable.addRow(new Object[] { list1.get(i), list2.get(i), ..., ... });

DefaultDataSet dds = new DefaultDataSet(fourColTable);
```

EDIT: If you want to insert many tables into a data sent, try it like this:

```
ITable[] tables = { new DefaultTable(...), new DefaultTable(...), ... };
```

Comment: Is there another way possible to create a defaultDataSet? I think it would be too much work to create a table first as there is loads of them. thanks

Comment: @EmmaMack I don't think so - not without creating some sort of metadata. What you have is a `java.util.List<someObject>`, that's not enough for a database. You need to tell it what field from `someObject` goes to which table and column. How could you go without it?

Comment: Ok, what I have done now is created a seperate class to carry out the defaultTable formatting of each table and return the defaultDataSet of each table to the dbunit class.  So this is workable.  However, can u tell me can I store multiple DefaultTable in one defaultDataSet? i tried   DefaultTable[] dataTables = new DefaultTable[] { //each defaultTable }. and tried DefaultDataSet dds = new DefaultDataSet(dataTables); but get an error... needs to be ITable[].  Is there another solution?  THanks

Comment: @EmmaMack See my edit. Look how the tables' table is **declared** (arrays are not covariant in Java).